# In PHP, is it possible to load a file into multiple namespaces without exec?

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a strange case where I need to require a php file multiple times under a number of different namespaces.

The two obvious options to me are:

- have that PHP file duplicated with a different namespace declarations
- read the php file and exec it.

The first option is not going to work as I will not always have the option to duplicate the namespaces as I don't know all the namespaces that are going to need this "widget".

The second option is just downright EVIL... okay, well you get the point.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Can you provide some sudo code example? Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: A strange case indeed. Are you sure you really need it? You know a php file can have no namespaces at all, and it will be loaded within the namespace where it is included. Which is not a less evil than your 2 options tho.